# TFS Build notification options not populating build definitions

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfsbuild

downMy gated checkin reconcile message has stopped working. To troubleshoot I opened up Build Notifications options and see that the "Build notifications to monitor" list is blank.I restarted Visual studio, connected to the project server again in the IDE, rebooted the machine but still Build notification options are blank.

I have also deleted the Team Foundation local cache from %localappdata%/Microsoft/Team Foundation/5.0/Cache but to no result.

From what i understand the Build notification desktop tray app gets the connection to the server from the Connect option in Visual Studio IDE. All the settings look right but the problem persists. Any suggestions?

P.S : I have recently downgraded from Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate to Visual studio 2013 Pro.

[image]

Comment: Check that you're not launching the 2012 or 2010 version of the Build notification client. Each version has it's own list of servers and projects.

Comment: It's the correct version of Build notification client.

Comment: Actually that was it. Incorrect executable path. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each version of Visual Studio (2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 etc) installs its own newer version of this tool. Each under a different path that contains the Visual Studio version.

Make sure you're launching the correct one, or register your TFS version inside the latest version of Visual Studio installed and use that (since it will be able to connect to any and all versions of TFS).