# TFS Build Notifications not showing any projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I have multiple team projects in TFS (Visual Studio Online), each having 1 or more build definitions (non-XAML). I'd like to use the Build Notifications tray app to monitor these builds, however none of my projects show in the options:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the build definitions for one of my team projects to show that they are defined and enabled:

[image]

Things I've tried but did not help:

- [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841062/tfs-build-notification-options-not-populating-build-definitions) identifies the same problem but the answer did not help me. I am already using the correct version of the Build Notifications app -- I have Visual Studio 2013 (the latest version installed on my computer) and I am using BuildNotificationApp.exe from *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE*.
- In Visual Studio I reconnected to my team projects.
- Based on a comment I read somewhere, I emptied all temp folders and restarted my computer.

Any idea what's going on? Is it a bug? Is some security restriction getting in the way? Are Visual Studio Online's build definitions no longer compatible with the Build Notifications app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, TFS build notification tool does not support new Team Builds.

You can try  [Catlight build notifications](https://catlight.io). This app will show you a build status in tray, and it works with both - new Team Builds and old XAML builds.

[image: Catlight build status in tray]